# Is there a way to have two values from one variable/constant in Swift?

Tags: swift, constants

I currently have to make a school project where I have to write into a textfield a food and the values of the price and calories must appear to the user. Is there a way to have a variable or better yet, a constant have more than one value? Thanks

Comment: use a struct, is very easy. read up on structs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Tuples` to save several values for one variable. A tuple can hold values with different types.

Here an example:

```
let lasagne = (1200, 5.50)
print("The lasagne has \(lasagne.0) kCal and costs \(lasagne.1)$")
```

you can also name the inner elements and then access them by their name:

```
let pizza = (calories: 900, price: 4)
print("The pizza has \(pizza.calories) kCal and costs \(pizza.price)$")
```